# Sorting and Plotting data from a text file

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a **huge** dataset i a text file from which I want to get a plot. The dataset inside the file is like this:

```
Length     No.of times
20            30
15            45
12            10
20            120
15            56
```

Now, on this dataset I first want to sort it on the basis of Length like this:

```
Length     No.of times
12            10
15            45
15            56
20            120
20            30
```

Once I have sorted the data then I want to plot Length on X-axis and No.of times on Y axis.

How can I do this type of sorting in Matlab and then do the plotting. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read the data, assuming you have two vectors, `Length`, and `NoOfTimes`:

```
[~,bb]=sort(Length);
plot(Length(bb),NoOfTimes(bb),'.')
```

Comment: When I use [~,bb] it gives me the error: expression or statement is incorrect  possibly unbalanced (, { or [

Comment: First, check if all the brackets are well defined. Second, which MATLAB version you have? For early versions just write `[aa,bb]=sort(Length);`, while actually you don't need variable `aa`.